# Variable scope with jQuery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I wrote the following function:

```
function getData() {

   var data;
   $(function () {
      $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function (ipinfo) {
          data = ipinfo;
          console.log(data);
     })
   })

console.log(data);
}
```

The problem with the above is the 2nd console.log doesn't retain the info from the assignment inside the jQuery and logs an undefined object. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong, but I believe it to be something quite minor. However, as much as I've searched online, I haven't found an answer for this particular problem.

Comment: `.jQuery.getJSON()` returns results asynchronously. You can use `.then()` or `async/await` to use `data` through the code once the jQuery promise object is fulfilled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It's not a scope issue, it's an order of operation issue.  The second `console.log` is executed before the first due to the nature of asynchronicity and order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line: **Javascript is Asynchronous.**

While many struggle to figure out what it exactly means, a simple example could possibly explain you that.

1. You request some data from a URL.
2. When the data from second URL is received, you wish to set a variable with the received data.
3. You wish to use this outside the request function's callback (after making the request).

For a conventional programmer, it is very hard to grasp that the order of execution in case of JavaScript will not be 1,2 and then 3 but rather 1,3,2.

Why this happens is because of Javascript's event-loop mechanism where each asynchronous action is tied with an event and callbacks are called only when the event occurs. Meanwhile, the code outside the callback function executes without holding on for the event to actually occur.

In your case:

```
var data;
$(function () {
   $.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io', function (ipinfo) {//async  function's callback
      data = ipinfo;
      console.log(data);//first console output
  })
})

console.log(data);//second console output
```

While the async function's callback is executed when the data is received from the `$.getJSON` function, javascript proceeds further without waiting for the `callback` to assign the value to the `data` variable, causing you to log `undefined` in the console (which is the value of the `data` variable when you call `console.log`.

I hope I was able to explain that.!